# Regex to find exactly 4 decimal values in a row

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

i need help with a regular expression to find specific blocks in a file. These blocks have 4 decimal numbers with comma and whitespace seperator. Example:

```
1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112
```

The regex i need is:
DECIMAL,DECIMAL DECIMAL,DECIMAL (exactly 4 values)

```
1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112 #True
1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112 1.2,3.45 #False
text 1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112 text #True
```

Thx for help.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: The language is Python.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
^\D*([\d\.]+,[\d\.]+\s[\d\.]+,[\d\.]+)\D*$
```

I think this will solve your problem. I have attached the screen-shot using the above regular expression. I hope this helps you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use an anchored regex like below.

```
r'^\D*\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+ \d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+\D*$'
```

`\D*` matches any non-digit character , zero or more times.

**Example:**

```
>>> s = ['1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112', '1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112 1.2,3.45', 'text 1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112 text']
>>> for i in s:
        if re.match(r'^\D*\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+ \d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+\D*$', i):
            print(i)


1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112
text 1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112 text
```

To print only the block.

```
>>> for i in s:
        m = re.match(r'^\D*(\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+ \d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+)\D*$', i)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))


1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112
1.23,4.567 8.9,10.1112
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version . I am assuming that either "," and "white space" would separate the numbers ( with decimal )

```
/(\d+\.\d+(,|\s+)?){4}/
```

if you think there is a pattern that has both "," and "space"

```
/(\d+\.\d+,\s+){4}/
```